# Idea for a post apocalyptic civilization in Britain?

Tags: culture

A nuclear war happens, and most of Europe, Russia, North America, and Asia are destroyed. Technology has been knocked back to pre-industrial societies at best, pre
agricultural at worst. England was hit pretty hard, about 240 nukes landed. The war was 500 years ago. While my story takes please mostly in North America, parts of it take place in the good ol’ United Kingdom. So I, being an American and all, have no idea what the culture should be like over there.

**What should the post apocalyptic culture be like in UK?**

Comment: Well, you can start with H. G. Wells' books to get the idea.

Comment: @Alexander which one specifically

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddley_Walker

Comment: H. G. Wells is arguably the father of the "dystopian future" genre, and his "The Time Machine" and "The War of the Worlds" are most known works.

Comment: No amount of reading comes even close to living in the place proper. Move there.

Comment: Talos, you know this will get closed, but you can salvage it.  Try adding some clarity on how long after the war this is and how badly England was damaged.  What sort of tech do you envision these people having.  If you want references to literature that has depicted such a world and you want to borrow from previously built worlds, that is a fair request .  Buff this up to repel the close voters!

Comment: The UK is actually very regional and particular. Depending on which county and areas were hit, the surviving civilizations will arise and be based on the areas not stuck. The extreme ends of the islands, mountainous areas of Wales and much of Ireland will survive, so competing kingdoms will aries from these roots.

Comment: @Alexander HG Wells died in 1946. He may be the Father of Science Fiction, but his works are hardly relevant to designing a post-apocalyptic British culture 500 years after the nuclear war. Wells is, of course, worth reading in his own right.

Comment: This question is in the reopen queue, but it has not been sufficiently narrowed to permit reopening.  Developing an entire culture is too broad and making cultural suggestions is too opinion-based.  Please review our [help] for more information.